# Execute task or process after expiry date

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

I have a form which also have a field called expiryDate.
So when this form is submitted and the expiryDate is say 10-08-2017 1: 05pm, i want a task to execute immediately on the expired record.

I've been able to use Spring  @Scheduled and Cron to execute the task.

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/4 ? *  *") // At second :00, at minute :00, very 4 hours starting at 00am, of every day
    public void printMessage(){
        List<User> userList =  userService.findAllUsers();
        for (User item : userList){
            System.out.println("First Name :: " + item.getFirstName());
        }
        System.out.println("I am called by Spring scheduler");
    }
```

Using Cron means the job will execute at a particular time say every 4 hours.

In this scenario, If there is no expired record or event for a whole day, the job will still be executed which will consume the system resources.

So instead of using a Cron or Scheduler, is the any other way to execute the task immediately the record expired.

My main concern is to only run the task when a record or an event expired.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend read the Spring TaskScheduler abstraction section of Task Execution Spring documentation here is the link https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-scheduler see the trigger section

Comment: I've check, but i don't think its closer to what i want. Something like `ScheduledFuture schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime);` looks closer. Has anyone done something like this before?