# CRON Job do not perform on given expired schedule after deployment

Tags: java, asynchronous, jboss, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a CRON that will run every 3am written in seam project. This application shutdown at 1am. Then scheduled restart at 5am written in Shell Script.
The question may sound crazy but why did the application not run the scheduled task which is in the past after application deployment? This task did not run for that day.

**NOTE**: Not a spring project. No Database interaction.

Any answer would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If the application shuts down at 1 AM and restarts at 3 AM then how will the CRON run? Shouldn't the application be in running state for CRON to run?

Comment: It starts at 5am @RohanShah. Yes, I know that it should be on running state. But my question is, why it did not run the scheduled task from past which never ran.

Comment: Because that is not how CRON works. If the time has gone and the application was in stopped state then the job won't run. It will then run at the next 3 AM i.e. tommorow at 3 AM. It doesn't run the delayed jobs. If at 3 AM the application is running then it will execute or else it will wait for 3 AM of the next day.

Comment: I completely understand that. Does it have a documentation about its limitation?

Comment: Not exactly a documentation but this might help
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Comment: Thank you @RohanShah, with plain Unix, I know it is not possible. Since this is not limited to that, there is a way in java that I just dug. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168607/java-run-the-cron-job-task-even-schedule-has-come/59405071#59405071)

Comment: Yes I will surely!